# Ubuntu keeps hanging

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I recently started using ubuntu 14.04 (Dual booting with win 8.1).

It was working fine until I ran the following code on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

I just wanted he "Open terminal here" option :P

Since then, its been hanging a lot. Every time this happens, I put my laptop to sleep and open it again, and its fine.

But it's really annoying (It must have hung like two times while typing this).

What should I do??

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your laptop having a nvidia-card and your are using the nvidia drivers. then this hanging may be caused by the nvidia prime freeze

Comment: Yes, and yes I am!
Should I switch from "NVIDIA binary driver" to "X.Org X server"?

Comment: Yes. You should  or select power saving mode from nvidia drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by nvidia drivers .. You can do two things. Either switch from nvidia drivers to nouview or bumblebee drivers. Or you can select the intel power saving mode in nvidia drivers.there might be some problem in selecting the powersaving mode. If there is problem you need to set update-alternatives. Or switch from nvidia drivers